# Keep text from overlapping with the div before

Tags: html, css

I have a table of contents that I want to keep the image on the far left and centralize the text, but when the text is too big, it overlaps with the image on the left. I want to keep this from happening, is there any way for that? Keep in mind, I'm finishing a project made by someone else so I don't want to make major changes.

The HTML:

```
<td class="text-center cart-product">
   <h2>
      <div>
         <img src="{{ item.product.image.url }}" alt="{{ item.product.title }}">
      </div>                        
      <div>
         <a>{{ item.product.title }}</a>
      </div>
   </h2>
</td>
```

The CSS:

```
.cart-product h2 a {
  color: #d85044;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}

.cart-product img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

.cart-product h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70px auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't see an issue when I run your code, so I must be misunderstanding what you mean by "when the text is too big" and "overlaps with the image on the left".

Comment: The text inside the <a> is supposed to be dynamic, meaning it's looking good if it's less than 30 characters. I don't want to put a character limit too, so I'm looking for a way to make some kind of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. I would suggest taking a look at three CSS attributes that might help in your project.

`overflow-wrap: break-word;`

`break-word: break-all;`

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Try each attribute independently, and know the proper value that can be used for each attribute to test which value fits the best.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure if I understand the situation, but you can add a scroll bar to the text and keep it at a sensible width with

```
#txt {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and then be sure to add the id in the right tag

```
<div id="txt">
     <a>{{ item.product.title }}</a>
</div>
```